# Trying to set the anti-aliasing property in autodesk forge (for 2D model/floor plan)

Tags: autodesk-forge

Trying to set the anti-aliasing property in autodesk forge (for 2D model/floor plan)
I have adding custom text geometry in my forge viewer but strigling to imrove it's quality.
Tried setQualityLevel (viewer3d.setQualityLevel(true, true)) to set the anti-aliasing on but it didn't improved the qulity/ or anti-aliasing does not seems to be working?
Attaching both images below.
with [anti-aliasingoff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A10Rc.png)

and [anti-aliasing on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETyUL.png)

Thanks

I have checked the implementation of Forge viewer and captured some more screenshots to explain the problem again.This time I am capturing geometry created by the autodesk forge measurement tool so that we can target the real problem.

In Autodesk 3d viewer we have this option to enable disable the anti-aliasing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBeJp.png)

if we set it to on the result is below one. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3dsB.png)

We can see edges are still jagged but not as compared to what results if we set it to off.

Following is the result of anti-aliasing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLZnz.png)

Observe the red line and difference that anti-aliasing flag makes in the overall quality of the rendered data.

We need to solve the same problem in 2D version of viewer but unfortunately the option to toggle anti-aliasing is not present in 2D forge viewer.I know that the implementation of anti-aliasing present in Autodesk Forge is FXAA and not sure if there are any limitations for 2d in it? if not then can you please let us know if we can expect this future version of Autodesk forge ? Please let us know

Answer (score 0):

Please note that according to the [API reference](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setqualitylevel-usesao-usefxaa) the antialiasing is:

> Not applicable to 2D.

That is most likely why the settings have no effect on your 2D drawing.

Comment: Yes Petr, I missed it. In our case we are adding text geometry using overlay manager and the quality of rendring is not that good for those text geometries. Is there any way to achive antialiasing in 2D ?